# R- combine two variables with same character outputs to use in logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, paste

I've looked up what to do in this case and haven't found much information that I could use, so any advice would be greatly appreciated

I have a dataset that separates males and females for certain variables. I would like to combine them and use the combined variable in logistic regression.

example of how data looks

```
male<- c("weekly","monthly","","never","","","weekly")
female<- c("","","never","","daily","weekly","")
df<-data.frame(male,female)
```

My code looks like this

```
df$combined<- paste(df$male,df$female)
model_00_<- glm(formula= df$outcome ~ df$main_predictor + df$combined, data=df, family=binomial(link="logit"))
exp(cbind(OR=coef(model_00_),confint(model_00_)))
```

but when I do the output looks like this (arbitrary numbers for simplicity)

```
                     OR      2.5%     97.5%            
intercept            9         6        11
daily                4         3        7
weekly               3          2        6
monthly              2.5        1.5      4
never                0.75       0.6     0.9
daily                4         3        7
weekly               3          2        6
monthly             2.5        1.5      4  
never                NA         NA      NA
```

I think this is happening because of the "paste" function but I am unsure as to how I can marry the two variables without the "paste" function

Comment: Hey Ryan, please provide a reproducible data example, e.g. by using `dput()`. It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: `dplyr::coalesce` will probably do what you want but, as @fbeese says, a MRE would be helpful.

Comment: And what about your output looks odd?

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to stackoverflow (and coding in general) and am still learning the ropes on how to post questions in a efficient way!

Comment: I haven't used dput() a lot so I just made a quick example df. does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, `paste` is a bad solution because it adds whitespace between the things being pasted. But I do not like using `paste0` either, because it doesn't really consider the original variables as data -- just pastes them together as characters.

As Limey's comment above mentions, I think `coalesce` is the better solution than either. `coalesce(x, y)` simply takes the value of `x` unless it is NA or NULL, in which case the value of `y` is used. Thus:

```
male <- c("weekly", "monthly", NA, "never", NA, NA, "weekly")
female <- c(NA, NA, "never", NA, "daily", "weekly", NA)

df <- data.frame(male, female)
df
> df
     male female
1  weekly   <NA>
2 monthly   <NA>
3    <NA>  never
4   never   <NA>
5    <NA>  daily
6    <NA> weekly
7  weekly   <NA>

library(dplyr)
desired_output <- coalesce(male, female)
desired_output

> desired_output
[1] "weekly"  "monthly" "never"   "never"   "daily"   "weekly"  "weekly"
```

However, note that if your empty cells in the original data file have any whitespace in them, or were empty strings (""), then `coalesce` would not work. An empty string is different than a missing value.